# how to make <?php the_permalink() ?> follow?

Tags: permalinks, nofollow

i use this code to show posts of wp

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

but all link are nofollow. why they are nofollow wen there is nofollow rel? how to make tem follow?

Comment: Since you have coded the full HTML for the link, the only possible reason this link could become `nofollow` is if you have a script from a theme or plugin that is adding it. There's not enough information available to say any more than that. Try disabling plugins until the issue is resolved. Then you know the culprit and can either deactivate it or contact the author for a fix.

Answer (score -1):

simply add this

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="follow"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

Comment: is there rel="follow" tag in html? i don think so. it doesnt work. still they are nofollow